# Pass character-wise visual selection to an external command

Tags: visual-mode, external-command, register

I want to VISUAL select a piece of text character-wise and pass it to an external command.

For example I want to select only the URL from the the text below

```
abcde www.google.com abcde
```

and open it in the default browser.

But after I VISUAL selected it and ran the command

```
:call system('xdg-open', @*)
```

nothing happened

But the register `*` was filled with the selected contents. I tested it with:

```
:echo @*
www.google.com
```

What is the right command to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

prototype of system is:

```
system({cmd} [, {input}])
```

according to :help system()

```
If {input} is a string it is written to a pipe and passed as
stdin to the command.  The string is written as-is, line
separators are not changed.
```

so your final command becomes something like this:

```
echo www.google.com | xdg-open
```

which doesn't make sense, as xdg-open doesn't read from stdin. you can call

```
echo system('xdg-open', @*)
```

to check error message.

At last you can call system like this:

```
call system('xdg-open ' . @*)
                     ^ don't miss space
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also do `:!xdg-open <C-r><C-w>` to shell out and grab the word under the cursor.

I’m not sure how this handles a WORD like `www.google.com`; it may be that `<C-r><C-a>` is necessary

Comment: I think you mean `<C-r><C-a>` rather than `<C-W>`, don't you?

Comment: @user98761 yep, thanks